# 3D Touch(Quick Actions) leading to UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, 3dtouch

Is a way to open a specific View Controller from a Quick Action. I have the following code below in the App Delegate to open a specific View Controller. My app has the same design as the snapchat app i.e. with different View Controllers embedded in a scroll view and I would like to target a specific View Controller e.g. Sunday View Controller.

The idea is to present either the first, second or third Items as selected from the quick action items.

```
  func handleShortCutItem(shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem) -> Bool {



 var handled = false


    guard ShortcutIdentifier(fullType: shortcutItem.type) != nil else {
        return false
    }

    guard let shortcutType = shortcutItem.type as String? else {
        return false
    }

    switch (shortcutType) {
    case ShortcutIdentifier.First.type:

        //Present the Add View Controller
        handled = true


        let mondayVC : MondayViewController = MondayViewController(nibName: "MondayViewController", bundle: nil)
        self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(mondayVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

        break

    case ShortcutIdentifier.Second.type:

        //Present the View Controller related to this Screen
        handled = true

        let fridayVC : FridayViewController = FridayViewController(nibName: "FridayViewController", bundle: nil)
        self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(fridayVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

        break

    case ShortcutIdentifier.Third.type:

        //Present the View Controller related to this Screen
        handled = true

        let sundayVC : SundayViewController = SundayViewController(nibName: "SundayViewController", bundle: nil)
        self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(sundayVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

        break

    default:
        break
    }

    return handled

}
```

The add delegate code to run this function is:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, performActionForShortcutItem shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: (Bool) -> Void) {

        let handledShortcutItem = self.handleShortCutItem(shortcutItem)
        completionHandler(handledShortcutItem)
    }
```